# Doing a windows files count down of installing windows updates

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, auto-update, insert-update

This is the code I am working on with right now. The code run the *.msu file from a dir onto the system for update. Looking to add a number count down the files from 9 to 1 so can tell The code is using a bat file. where I am all most done with the install. 
There is the code

```
      @echo off
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
      'This part code found the number of msu files
      for /f %%A in ('dir *.msu') do ( 
      set files=!dirs!
      set dirs=%%A
      )
      'This part of code put the file msu file name
      for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.msu') do ( 
      echo == Installing Updates == "%files%" "%%A" ...
      %%A /quiet /norestart
      )

      echo.
      echo ########################################
      echo.
      echo == Updates installed ==
      echo.
      echo == Press any key to restart ==&pause>nul
      echo.
      shutdown.exe /r /t 0
```

I would the output to look like this if can

---

== Installing Updates == "9" "file" ...

== Installing Updates == "8" "File" ...

---

I just need help a way of every time install update it make the number go down by one.  Any help would be good. Thank for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but is this what you want?

```
  @echo off
  for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.msu') do (
  echo == Installing Updates == "%%A" ...
  %%A /quiet /norestart
  )
  for /l %%A in (9,-1,1) do (
  cls
  echo %%A
  ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1 >nul
  )
  cls
    echo.
    echo ########################################
    echo.
    echo == Updates installed ==
    echo.
    echo == Press any key to restart ==&pause>nul
    echo.
    shutdown.exe /r /t 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have to try it out

Answer (score 0):

Krii's answer should work fine. However there are easier ways. Such as the `timeout` command. The following will wait for ten seconds, and display a timer:

```
timeout 10
```

Or if you didn't want any output you could add `> nul` at the end of the command.

Another possibility is to exploit the `choice` command:

```
choice /c a /n /d a /t 10 > nul
```

That example also won't have any output. Of course the user can press the a key to cancel the countdown and continue the script, but I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have to try it out

Comment: Still working on it.. I just need to found a way to do the count down on each update and hotfix install in the system.